# In notice to end tennancy, must you specify the EXACT date of moving out?

Tags: canada, rental-property

When giving notice to end tenancy, must the exact date be given? For example if all of November has been paid for and the notice says you'll move on the 30st, and you end up moving on the 20th, is that technically breaking the contract?

Must the notice to end tenancy be worded in a particular way if the exact date is known, for example "I will be moving out on or before the 30st of November".

This is for a month to month. The information here appears to be a bit lacking for this scenario. http://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/housing-tenancy/residential-tenancies/ending-a-tenancy/tenant-notice

Comment: It would be 30th, not 30st.

Comment: Even if all your personal property is out on the 20th, if you still have the keys you haven't vacated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides Texas, which has some oddness in their tenancy laws, and perhaps a few other states, you are occupying a rental property and considered in tenancy as long as you control the property and have paid the rent.

There's nothing to stop you from renting an apartment, paying 6 months rent, and never setting foot inside...and the landlord in that circumstance has no particular rights of vacancy.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and that's the same here. I wasn't sure because could it be considered abandoning the property if you no longer live there?

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that as long as you pay your rent, you can move your belongings anytime you want. Some leases require you to inform the landlord if the unit is going to be empty for an extended period of time, so maybe inform your landlord as well. That said, they can't keep you from moving your belongings in or out of your unit.